# How to add rowid to a table with increment but group by another column?

Tags: mysql, addition, rowid

for example, i have a table1:

```
+---------------------+---------------+
| StartTime           | dIPaddr       |
+---------------------+---------------+
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:55 | 0.210.208.240 |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:55 | 0.210.243.93  |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:57 | 0.210.243.93  |
| 2014-04-09 08:40:00 | 0.210.243.93  |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:27 | 0.210.25.224  |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to get a result:

```
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
| StartTime           | dIPaddr       | rowid         |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 | 1             |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 | 2             |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:55 | 0.210.208.240 | 3             ｜
| 2014-04-09 08:39:55 | 0.210.243.93  | 1             ｜
| 2014-04-09 08:39:57 | 0.210.243.93  | 2             ｜
| 2014-04-09 08:40:00 | 0.210.243.93  | 3             ｜
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  | 1             ｜
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  | 2             ｜
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  | 3             ｜
| 2014-04-09 13:02:27 | 0.210.25.224  | 4             ｜
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The rowid is  automatic increasing, but group by dIPaddr.
I try to use

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN rowId int not null auto_increment 
group by dIPaddr;
```

But it just show me error. How to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not directly available in InnoDB.  Something like it available in MyISAM, where you have a 2-column PRIMARY KEY(dIPaddr, rowId).  This would switch to such (I think):

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN rowId int not null auto_increment,
ADD PRIMARY KEY(dIPaddr, rowId),
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

No GROUP BY is used.  (But that was a nice guess.)

After that, you don't include rowId in your INSERTs, and the system will automatically provide it.

If you want to stay with InnoDB, then the table could be retrofitted with rowId using @variables.  But it would not automatically provide rowId for new rows unless you wrote a TRIGGER.